# Sound Not Working on Ubuntu 22.04 but working in Windows

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Here are the outputs to some commands:

```
aplay -l: aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

lspci -v: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: nCipher Security CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 139
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at b1132000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1131000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Memory at b1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at b1122000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at b1130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b111c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SCS3 (prog-if 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SCS3
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at b112f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 9f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 9f801000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPSS: I2C Controller #2
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPSS: I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at 9f802000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at b112b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at b1120000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at b112a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 3090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 3080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Memory at b1129000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at 9f803000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:1a.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c4 (prog-if 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1127000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02a8
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at 9f804000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ab
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at 9f805000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device 2782:0200
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 140
    Memory at b1118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b1124000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci

lsmod | grep snd: snd_soc_sof_es8336     20480  0
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common    20480  1 snd_soc_sof_es8336
snd_sof_probes         20480  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     86016  0
snd_soc_dmic           16384  0
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   139264  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               208896  3 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_probes
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    69632  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_es8316         49152  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec         176128  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_core          368640  8 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_sof_es8336,snd_sof_probes,snd_soc_es8316,snd_soc_dmic
snd_hda_core          114688  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_compress           24576  2 snd_soc_core,snd_sof_probes
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq                77824  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_pcm               155648  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_soc_es8316,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   114688  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_sof_es8336,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd

dmesg | grep -i audio: dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

I also did sudo alsa force-reload but to no avail.

Can someone kindly assist.

Thanks